# format no valid records found in tracefile using genHTML on coverage.dat generated by bazel in lcov

Tags: html, macos, bazel, lcov

Team,
I am able to successfully generated the coverage.dat file but I cannot generate htlm to view the report. anything that am missing? am new to this.

`./bazel coverage --combined_report=lcov //src/teams/test/...`

**output**

```
Command> ./bazel coverage --combined_report=lcov //src/teams/test/...
INFO: Invocation ID: 48b15c3a-43bb-435c-97d5-e608703cc53a
INFO: Using default value for --instrumentation_filter: "^//src/teams/test/keys[/:],^//src/teams/test/server[/:],^//src/teams/test/store/postgres[/:],^//src/teams/test/tools/keyrotate[/:],^//src/teams/test/vault[/:]".
INFO: Override the above default with --instrumentation_filter
INFO: Build option --instrumentation_filter has changed, discarding analysis cache.
DEBUG: Rule 'distroless' indicated that a canonical reproducible form can be obtained by modifying arguments shallow_since = "1564086429 -0400"
DEBUG: Repository distroless instantiated at:
  /Users/userme/code/company/git-team/product/WORKSPACE:32:20: in <toplevel>
  /private/var/tmp/_bazel_userme/e6e1d0cbd051dd43ed59dca5541f019d/external/product/wkspc/phase0.bzl:62:23: in static_repositories
Repository rule git_repository defined at:
  /private/var/tmp/_bazel_userme/e6e1d0cbd051dd43ed59dca5541f019d/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl:199:33: in <toplevel>
INFO: Analyzed 33 targets (68 packages loaded, 21664 targets configured).
INFO: Found 28 targets and 5 test targets...
INFO: LCOV coverage report is located at /private/var/tmp/_bazel_userme/e6e1d0cbd051dd43ed59dca5541f019d/execroot/product/bazel-out/_coverage/_coverage_report.dat
 and execpath is bazel-out/_coverage/_coverage_report.dat
INFO: From Coverage report generation:
Dec 09, 2022 11:36:27 AM com.google.devtools.coverageoutputgenerator.Main getTracefiles
INFO: Found 5 tracefiles.
Dec 09, 2022 11:36:27 AM com.google.devtools.coverageoutputgenerator.Main parseFilesSequentially
INFO: Parsing file bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/testlogs/src/teams/test/vault/vault_test/coverage.dat
Dec 09, 2022 11:36:27 AM com.google.devtools.coverageoutputgenerator.Main parseFilesSequentially
INFO: Parsing file bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/testlogs/src/teams/test/server/server_test/coverage.dat
Dec 09, 2022 11:36:27 AM com.google.devtools.coverageoutputgenerator.Main parseFilesSequentially
INFO: Parsing file bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/testlogs/src/teams/test/store/postgres/postgres_test/coverage.dat
Dec 09, 2022 11:36:27 AM com.google.devtools.coverageoutputgenerator.Main parseFilesSequentially
INFO: Parsing file bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/testlogs/src/teams/test/keys/keys_test/coverage.dat
Dec 09, 2022 11:36:28 AM com.google.devtools.coverageoutputgenerator.Main parseFilesSequentially
INFO: Parsing file bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/testlogs/src/teams/test/tools/keyrotate/keyrotate_test/coverage.dat
Dec 09, 2022 11:36:28 AM com.google.devtools.coverageoutputgenerator.Main getGcovInfoFiles
INFO: No gcov info file found.
Dec 09, 2022 11:36:28 AM com.google.devtools.coverageoutputgenerator.Main getGcovJsonInfoFiles
INFO: No gcov json file found.
Dec 09, 2022 11:36:28 AM com.google.devtools.coverageoutputgenerator.Main getProfdataFileOrNull
INFO: No .profdata file found.
Dec 09, 2022 11:36:28 AM com.google.devtools.coverageoutputgenerator.Main runWithArgs
WARNING: There was no coverage found.
INFO: Elapsed time: 65.521s, Critical Path: 52.28s
INFO: 247 processes: 25 disk cache hit, 75 internal, 146 darwin-sandbox, 1 worker.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 247 total actions
//src/teams/test/keys:keys_test                                    PASSED in 3.1s
  /private/var/tmp/_bazel_userme/e6e1d0cbd051dd43ed59dca5541f019d/execroot/product/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/testlogs/src/teams/test/keys/keys_test/coverage.dat
//src/teams/test/server:server_test                                PASSED in 1.1s
  /private/var/tmp/_bazel_userme/e6e1d0cbd051dd43ed59dca5541f019d/execroot/product/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/testlogs/src/teams/test/server/server_test/coverage.dat
//src/teams/test/store/postgres:postgres_test                      PASSED in 3.8s
  /private/var/tmp/_bazel_userme/e6e1d0cbd051dd43ed59dca5541f019d/execroot/product/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/testlogs/src/teams/test/store/postgres/postgres_test/coverage.dat
//src/teams/test/tools/keyrotate:keyrotate_test                    PASSED in 1.3s
  /private/var/tmp/_bazel_userme/e6e1d0cbd051dd43ed59dca5541f019d/execroot/product/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/testlogs/src/teams/test/tools/keyrotate/keyrotate_test/coverage.dat
//src/teams/test/vault:vault_test                                  PASSED in 2.3s
  /private/var/tmp/_bazel_userme/e6e1d0cbd051dd43ed59dca5541f019d/execroot/product/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/testlogs/src/teams/test/vault/vault_test/coverage.dat

Executed 5 out of 5 tests: 5 tests pass.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 247 total actions
```

**genHTML output**

```
 `genhtml /private/var/tmp/_bazel_userme/e6e1d0cbd051dd43ed59dca5541f019d/execroot/product/bazel-out/_coverage/_coverage_report.dat`
 
Reading data file _coverage_report.dat
genhtml: ERROR: no valid records found in tracefile _coverage_report.dat
```

i also tried this but same output.
https://bazel.build/configure/coverage
`genhtml --output genhtml "$(bazel info output_path)/_coverage/_coverage_report.dat"`

Comment: I am getting exactly the same problem in gitlab.com/yin2/language